# Invoke function with each argument

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, variadic-templates, variadic-functions

I'd like to invoke a function with each argument passed as a parameter pack.
I have already written a simple template function:

```cpp
template<class Function, class... Args>
auto for_each_arg(Function f, Args&&... args) {
    (f(std::forward<Args>(args)), ...);
}
```

It works fine when I use it with a function taking only one parameter:

```cpp
void foo(int a) { }
for_each_arg(foo, 1);
```

But when I try to call a function taking two and more arguments:

```cpp
void bar(int a, int b) { }
for_each_arg(bar, 1, 2);
```

it gives an error `too few arguments for call`. How could I fix it? A solution may be created in C++17.

Comment: Recursion is OK? Or do you want necessarily template folding solution?

Comment: Any solution is fine, it needn't be folding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void bar(int a, int b) { }
for_each_arg(
  [](auto&&tup){
    return std::apply(bar, decltype(tup)(tup));
  }
)(std::make_tuple(1, 2));
```

Here the caller bundles arguments into tuples, and we unpack them into the call.  This makes the packaging of which arguments go where clear.

We can move the apply call into the foreach function.  In theory we csn detect if the target accepts 1 argument, and if not unpack the argument as a tuple, but I advise against it.  To many things go wrong with muddled operations like that.

```
apply_foreach(f, tuples...)
```

is a clean and easy to specify function.

Comment: Thanks, it works fine. I have changed my question a bit and now the correct function invoke is `for_each_arg([](auto&& tup) { return std::apply(bar, decltype(tup)(tup)); }, std::make_tuple(1, 2));` - if you could correct it in your answer, please. Sorry for confuse.

Comment: Agree automatically detecting arity would just be confusing. For one thing, if the functor type is a class with overloaded or variadic `operator()`, there isn't an obviously correct behavior.

Comment: @achep plus, modify airity from 2 to 3, and some poor sod calling it with 6 gets really surprised.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont I have one more question: is there any need to create functions as mine `for_each_arg()`? I am looking at your solution and it seems that `std::apply()` is sufficient and we don't need to wrap it with any addition functions like `for_each_arg()`.

Comment: @mucha no, it just makes the calling site less messy.

Answer (score 1):

The good-old recursion way is simple

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename F>
void invoke_two_args (F)
 { }

template <typename F, typename A0, typename A1, typename ... Args>
void invoke_two_args (F f, A0 && a0, A1 && a1, Args && ... args)
 {
   f(std::forward<A0>(a0), std::forward<A1>(a1));

   invoke_two_args(f, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
 }

void bar(int a, int b)
 { std::cout << "bar: " << a << ' ' << b << '\n'; }

int main ()
 {
   // compile
   invoke_two_args(bar, 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13);

   // compilation error: wrong number of arguments
   // invoke_two_args(bar, 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17);
 }
```

This is a good solution only if the list of the arguments isn't too long.

Comment: Thank you for your solution, but Yakk - Adam`s solution is pretty shorter and seems to be more understandable.

Comment: @Michal - the Yakk's solution is also more flexible (not only two arguments but, generically, n arguments).

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
template <typename F, typename... Args>
auto curry(F&& f, Args&&... args) {
  if constexpr (std::is_invocable_v<F, Args...>) {
    return std::invoke(std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  } else {
    return [&](auto&&... more_args) {
      return curry(std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Args>(args)..., more_args...);
    };
  }
}

int foo(int a, int b) { return a + b; }

// usage
auto func = curry(foo);
func(1)(2);
```

Comment: I think you have issue with `func(1, 2, 3, 4);` which expects `foo(1,2); foo(3, 4);`.

Comment: foo only have two arguments, what would you expected, when you call foo(1, 2, 3, 4)

Comment: OP shows a `for_each_arg` which allows to call `f` (of arity 1) for each argument (even if OP's example use only one :/). a function of arity 2 should take element two by two. I think you misunderstand OP's question (which is not very clear IMO).